# Why my HTML button is above my Flash content in IE8 instead of behind?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer

I'm searching for a solution for several hours now, without success.

I have a simple Flex/Flash/SWF object that I want to use to read a local file and return a base64 version of it.

The source files can be found on GitHub : https://github.com/Country/FileToDataURI.as

With Firefox (last version), and IE9, when you move your mouse over the button and click, then the Flash object is called and opens a browse file window.
Except for IE8 (and IE7) : the button appears to be above the Flash content. So if you click on the button, it won't call the Flash object ! And if you move the mouse just after the button (on the right) you'll see the cursor changing because it detects the Flash object, and you can click on it. So it shows that the Flash works into IE8.

Everywhere I can read that Flash is always above the HTML, but not here for IE8....
I tried several things :

- call directly the object (without Google SWFObject);
- change the CSS (I thought that maybe the "display" option or "position" will impact the behavior);
- change the button by a A element;
- move around the object element in the page.

Some help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Finally I've created my own system that permits to do pretty much the same thing, and it now works : http://aymkdn.github.com/FileToDataURI/
This project permits to read a local file with Flash or Javascript and to return the base64 encoded content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the wmode to 'opaque'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the z-index in css of the flash element to say 10?

Comment: Yes. I tried the z-index on different elements, with no success.